# How to style the imagefied in django forms?

Tags: python, django, image, image-uploading

I have a user model and user can upload multiple photos in another model. So, when updatging/creating the user, I have used inline forms to add/update photos also. The default django image upload field rendering is not very good. It displays details like the current image url, remove checkbox, file upload field and other messages(Currently,Change etc). This is not attractive at all. I mean for an admin interface, it is ok; but when it comes to end user interface, I have to say its not good enough. I have found ways to display thumbnail instead of image_url from database. But I still need it to be better. Is there anyway I can render it as below?

The drag drop function is not required as for each image i want to display the widget and the image itself as background of widget in edit forms with change option. Is there any way to do this?

[image: Sample Upload widjet]

Comment: check https://github.com/sigurdga/django-dropzone-upload there are multiple options to display thumbnails and individualized Text etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the link in the Comment with that Plugin its quite easy.
Optional you could use Widget Tweaks and use a cheap trick like:

```css
    .dropzone{
     margin-top: 5px;
     width: 360px;
     background-color: rgba(225,225,225,0.5) !important;
     border-radius: 5px;
     height:140px;
     border: 3px dashed green;
     padding-top: 150px;
    }
    .textForDropzone{
      pointer-events:none;
      padding: 10px; 
      margin-left: 130px; 
 
      color:black;
      margin-top: -110px; 
      z-index:10000;
     }
```

```html
 <form method="POST"...>
  
     <form id="uploadFiles" class="dropzone" >
      <span class="mainop">2. Upload Image: </span>
      <input type="text" class="dropzone">
      <h3 class="textForDropzone"> Drop Image here or click to upload </h3>
```

You expand the input field and make it look like a drop zone with text inside etc....

code would look like this if you use widget tweaks

```
<form method="POST"...>
{% load widget_tweaks %}
{% csrf_token %}
<form id="uploadFiles" class="dropzone" >
  <span class="mainop">2. Upload a Image: </span>{{ formUP.image|add_class:"dropzone" }} 

  <h3 class="textForDropzone"> Drop Image here or click to upload </h3>
```

Comment: Appreciate your quick help. Let me try this out.